# How to Instantiate my code utilizing C++11 unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, smart-pointers

In my experimental game engine I'm currently creating some game sub-systems out on the heap with raw pointers. Basically, my derived classes use their constructors to call a protected constructor within base which news up these sub-systems for them. My code for this is like so:

Entity.h (Base class)

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>

namespace BlazeGraphics{ class Graphics; }
namespace BlazePhysics{ class Physics; }
namespace BlazeInput{ class Controller; }

namespace BlazeGameWorld
{
    class Entity
    {
    protected:
        Entity(BlazeGraphics::Graphics* renderer, BlazePhysics::Physics* physics, BlazeInput::Controller* controller);

        BlazeGraphics::Graphics* renderer;
        BlazePhysics::Physics* physics;
        BlazeInput::Controller* controller;
    };
}
```

Entity.cpp

```
#include "Graphics/Graphics.h"
#include "Input/Controller.h"
#include "Physics/Physics.h"
#include "Input/Input.h"
#include "Entity.h"

namespace BlazeGameWorld
{
    Entity::Entity()
    {}

    Entity::Entity(BlazeGraphics::Graphics* renderer, BlazePhysics::Physics* physics, BlazeInput::Controller* controller) :
        renderer(renderer),
        physics(physics),
        controller(controller),
        position(0.0f, 0.0f),
        velocity(0.0f, 0.0f)
    {
    }

    Entity::~Entity()
    {
    }
}
```

Player.cpp (Derived)

```
#include "Graphics/Graphics.h"
#include "Input/Input.h"
#include "Input/PlayerController.h"
#include "Physics/Physics.h"
#include "Player.h"

namespace BlazeGameWorld
{
    Player::Player() :
        Entity(new BlazeGraphics::Graphics, new BlazePhysics::Physics, new BlazeInput::PlayerController)
    {
    }

    Player::~Player()
    {
    }
}
```

How would I update() this code to properly utilize C++11's unique_ptr? I'm having trouble figuring out how to initialize this smart ptr properly in my classes.

Comment: I would caution using unique_ptr for everything. I would suggest taking a minute to look and see what types of objects that will need to be accessed from different translation units and classes from the overall project design and for those that fit this description I would use a shared_ptr instead. Now as for an object that would only exist once and would have a life time of the application, then it would make sense to have a unique_ptr of that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's extremely easy. You just change all your raw pointers definitions to `std::unique_ptr`, and basically you're done.

```
std::unique_ptr<BlazeGraphics::Graphics> renderer;
```

Unique pointers are initialized the same way you initialize raw pointers. They will be deleted automatically when the object that holds them dies, so you do *not* need to release memory manually in the destructor (if you have any `delete <...>` statements, remove them).

You also do not need to change the code that uses the pointers, since the objects they point to are accessed with `->` operator, same as with raw pointers.

Comment: Beware of the differences in semantics! `unique_ptr` implies ownership, raw pointer doesn't. If you can't find a corresponding `delete` for every new `unique_ptr` it may mean you don't own the object.

Comment: @RustyX unless you have code that leaks every object because it has no deletes, like the example in the question.

Comment: The base class constructor would have to `std::move` from its parameters in the initialization if you change it's signature to use `unique_ptr`s (Which you should)

Comment: What about if I wanted to utilize std::make_unique? I've only ever seen examples in straight line code and not in classes like the way I have.

Comment: @Jason `std::make_unique` was only added in C++14. Since your question was about C++11, there was no such thing yet. (Everyone is always talking about `make_unique` like you can use it anywhere, even on questions that specifically reference C++11 or earlier.)